# Playlist not playing after the first video using BrightCove Exoplayer in android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, brightcove, exoplayer

I am trying to implement BrightCove Exoplayer in android. I was able to successfully implement playing individual videos. Now I am trying to play a playlist using Exoplayer. The first video in the playlist plays, at the end of the first video, the player doesn't play the next video in the playlist. It shows the beginning of the first video again; if I press the play button, the first video plays again. I want to achieve playing all the videos in the playlist continuously one after the other. Am I missing something? I am posting my code below:

MainActivity:

```
package com.brightcove.player.samples.exoplayer.basic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.brightcove.player.edge.VideoListener;
import com.brightcove.player.event.EventEmitter;
import com.brightcove.player.model.Playlist;
import com.brightcove.player.model.Video;
import com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView;
import com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcovePlayer;

import com.brightcove.player.media.Catalog;
import com.brightcove.player.media.PlaylistListener;

public class MainActivity extends BrightcovePlayer {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        brightcoveVideoView = (BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView) findViewById(R.id.brightcove_video_view);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Catalog catalog = new Catalog("MyToken");

        catalog.findPlaylistByReferenceID("MyPlaylistReference", new PlaylistListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaylist(Playlist playlist) {
                brightcoveVideoView.addAll(playlist.getVideos());
                //brightcoveVideoView.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                throw new RuntimeException(s);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Restoring saved position");
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "No saved state");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same plablem, you can find my solution there:
on your "onStateChanged" method release the actual player then prepare again a new one, you will be able to play a new video (on your preparePlayer remember to change the video URL)

```
@Override
    public void onStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        switch (playbackState) {
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                text += "buffering";
                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                if (playlistPosition < playlist.size() - 1) {
                    playlistPosition++;
                    releasePlayer();
                    preparePlayer();
                }
                text += "ended";
                break;
            default:
                text += "unknown";
                break;
        }
    }

 private void preparePlayer() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = new DemoPlayer(getRendererBuilder(playlist.get(playlistPosition).type)); [...]
```

I hope that can help you

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this at brightcove exoplayer level?